# Why is my html entity not converting after wrapping it around a template literal?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to make my mailto ahref tag dynamically change the subject tag.

**The Problem**

I encoded my email to HTML entities (`&#64;`) (I am using html entities to avoid spam-bots), so whenever I use  template literal to wrap around the HTML entities, it doesn't convert anymore.

**Example**

This is the current working mailto ahref tag that does not have dynamic subject (this one works)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h3>This is the current working mailto ahref tag that does not have dynamic subject</h3>



<a className="btn btn-primary mx-auto" href="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#114;&#121;&#108;&#121;&#50;&#49;&#51;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;?Subject=RandomSubject">
                    Contact Us
                  </a>
```

This is the mailto ahref tag that I attempting to do dynamic subjects

```html
<h3>The Problem I am trying to solve</h3>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<a
                    className="btn btn-primary mx-auto"
                    href={`&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#114;&#121;&#108;&#121;&#50;&#49;&#51;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;?Subject=${email}`}
                  >
                    Contact Us
                  </a>
```

**What I have tried**

I thought of putting the html entity in a variable and putting it inside the template literal; however it continue to not work.

```
//the code doesn't actually look like this but just a quick idea on what I did

const email = "&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#104;&#101;&#110;&#114;&#121;&#108;&#121;&#50;&#49;&#51;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;"

const subject = "random subject"

<a className="btn btn-primary mx-auto" href={`${email}?Subject=${subject}`}>
Contact Us
</a>
```

The next thing I tried was concatenate a regular string with a template string but that also didn't work

```
 const randomSubject = "hi";

 const email ="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#115;&#97;&#108;&#101;&#115;&#64;&#97;&#101;&#114;&#105;&#115;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#46;&#115;&#103;";

 const subject = `?Subject=${randomSubject}`;

<a className="btn btn-primary mx-auto" href={email + subject}>
```

I would appreciate any help like changing of the code, links to post that solve this problem , or correction on my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React deals with the DOM not with raw HTML.

The JavaScript value you pass gets assigned as the value of the attribute in the DOM.

It is **not** passed through an HTML parser.

If you want to encode the characters in the string, do so with JavaScript escape sequences instead.